# How to select the next HTML element in Puppeteer using $$. or $$eval?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

HTML structure is like the following:

```html
    <nav class='menu-315AG'>
        <a id='side-nav-1' href='something1' data-id='1'>text1</a>
        <div>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingA' data-id='1a'>text1a</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingB' data-id='1b'>text1b</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingC' data-id='1c'>text1c</a>
        </div>
        <a id='side-nav-2' href='something2' data-id='2'>text2</a>
        <div>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2A' data-id='2a'>text1a</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2B' data-id='2b'>text1b</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2C' data-id='2c'>text1c</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2D' data-id='2d'>text1c</a>
        </div>
        <a id='side-nav-3' href='something3' data-id='3'>text3</a>
        <div>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3A' data-id='3a'>text1a</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3B' data-id='3b'>text1b</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and I'm trying to get data from it in the following **format** :

```js
    [
        [
            1, 
            'text1', 
            'something1', 
            'side-nav-1', 
            [ 
                ['1a', 'text1a', 'something1/somethingA'],
                ['1b', 'text1b', 'something1/somethingB'],
                ['1c', 'text1c', 'something1/somethingC']
            ] 
        ],
        [
            2, 
            'text2', 
            'something2', 
            'side-nav-2', 
            [ 
                ['2a', 'text2a', 'something2/something2A'],
                ['2b', 'text2b', 'something2/something2B'],
                ['2c', 'text2c', 'something2/something2C'],
                ['2d', 'text2d', 'something2/something2D'] 
            ] 
        ],
        [
            3, 
            'text3', 
            'something3', 
            'side-nav-3', 
            [ 
                ['3a', 'text3a', 'something3/something3A'],
                ['3b', 'text3b', 'something3/something3B']
            ] 
        ]
    ]
```

now I can do this using the following working code, then looping through the **subcategories** array's hrefs for a partial match with hrefs in the **categories** array.

```js
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

    const html = `
        <nav class='menu-315AG'>
            <a id='side-nav-1' href='something1' data-id='1'>text1</a>
            <div>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingA' data-id='1a'>text1a</a>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingB' data-id='1b'>text1b</a>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingC' data-id='1c'>text1c</a>
            </div>
            <a id='side-nav-2' href='something2' data-id='2'>text2</a>
            <div>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2A' data-id='2a'>text2a</a>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2B' data-id='2b'>text2b</a>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2C' data-id='2c'>text2c</a>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2D' data-id='2d'>text2c</a>
            </div>
            <a id='side-nav-3' href='something3' data-id='3'>text3</a>
            <div>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3A' data-id='3a'>text3a</a>
                <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3B' data-id='3b'>text3b</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    `;


    let browser;
    (async () => {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const [page] = await browser.pages();
        await page.setContent(html);

        function ppp(str) {
            return console.dir(str, {depth: null,colors: true,maxArrayLength: null});
        }

        let categories = await page.$$eval('nav[class*=menu-]  a[id*=side-nav-]', el => el.map(x => {
            return [
                x.getAttribute('data-id'),              
                x.textContent.trim(), 
                x.getAttribute('href'),
                x.getAttribute('id'),
            ];
        }));

        let subcategories = await page.$$eval('nav[class*=menu-]  div > a[class*=side-sub-]', el => el.map(x => {
            return [
                x.getAttribute('data-id'),              
                x.textContent.trim(), 
                x.getAttribute('href'),
            ];
        }));

        for (let [i,] of categories.entries()) {
            categories[i].push([]); 
            for (let [j,] of subcategories.entries()) {
                if (subcategories[j][2].includes(categories[i][2])) {
                    categories[i][4].push(subcategories[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        ppp(categories); 

    })()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

Is there any way I can simplify this to do it without processing arrays?

p.s.
I have tried the following which returns nothing as the div isn't within the a tag, and tried ~ and + before the div tag which just gives an error.

```js
    let categoryPages = await this.page.$$('nav[class*=menu-]  a[id*=side-nav-]');

    let categories = [];
    for (let cat of categoryPages) {

        let text = await cat.evaluate(el => el.textContent.trim());
        let href = await cat.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('href'));
        let id = await cat.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('id'));
        let data_id = await cat.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('data-id'));              

        let subCategories = await cat.page.$$eval('div > a[class*=side-sub-]', el => el.map(x => {
                return [
                    x.getAttribute('data-id'),              
                    x.textContent.trim(), 
                    x.getAttribute('href'),
                ];
        }))

        categories.push([data_id, text, href, id, subCategories]);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want mixed-type arrays? Those are annoying to work with--it's not clear what `data[0]` is relative to `data.id`. Unless you have a special use case, I'd suggest using objects for mixed-type key-value structures, e.g. `[{id: 1, text: "text1", href: "something1", sideNav: "side-nav-1", children: [{id: "1a", ...}, ...]}, ...]`. Also, although I appreciate that you're trying to eliminate noise, I typically recommend against hiding the data with "something" everywhere--often, important characteristics get lost in the simplification.

Comment: @ggorlen I wrote the question using arrays as it is more compact.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem like a compelling reason to me unless you're in some kind of severely resource-constrained environment (a very rare case), so I'll hold to my suggestion that you reconsider your data structure to use objects as described above. Arrays are for collecting an ordered sequence of many things of the same type (like a list of people), objects are for collecting many unordered things of different types (like the various attributes that make up a person [height, weight, age, name, hair color, etc]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XPATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) to get the result you want

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `
    <nav class='menu-315AG'>
        <a id='side-nav-1' href='something1' data-id='1'>text1</a>
        <div>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingA' data-id='1a'>text1a</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingB' data-id='1b'>text1b</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingC' data-id='1c'>text1c</a>
        </div>
        <a id='side-nav-2' href='something2' data-id='2'>text2</a>
        <div>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2A' data-id='2a'>text2a</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2B' data-id='2b'>text2b</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2C' data-id='2c'>text2c</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2D' data-id='2d'>text2c</a>
        </div>
        <a id='side-nav-3' href='something3' data-id='3'>text3</a>
        <div>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3A' data-id='3a'>text3a</a>
            <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3B' data-id='3b'>text3b</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setContent(html);

    let cats = [];
    let categories = await page.$x("//a[contains(@id,'side-nav')]");
    for (let c of categories) {

        let subCategories = await c.$x("//following-sibling::div/a");   
        
        let subs = subCategories.map(async (x) => [
            await x.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('data-id')),
            await x.evaluate(el => el.textContent.trim()),
            await x.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('href'))        
        ]);

        cats.push([
            await c.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('data-id')),
            await c.evaluate(el => el.textContent.trim()),
            await c.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('href')),
            await c.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('id')),
            await Promise.all(subs)
        ]);
        
    }

    console.dir(cats,{depth: null});

})().catch(err => console.error(err)).finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: This works, and gets the correct output

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but missing some of the nesting:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.7.5

const html = `
<nav class='menu-315AG'>
  <a id='side-nav-1' href='something1' data-id='1'>text1</a>
  <div>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingA' data-id='1a'>text1a</a>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingB' data-id='1b'>text1b</a>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something1/somethingC' data-id='1c'>text1c</a>
  </div>
  <a id='side-nav-2' href='something2' data-id='2'>text2</a>
  <div>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2A' data-id='2a'>text1a</a>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2B' data-id='2b'>text1b</a>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2C' data-id='2c'>text1c</a>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something2/something2D' data-id='2d'>text1c</a>
  </div>
  <a id='side-nav-3' href='something3' data-id='3'>text3</a>
  <div>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3A' data-id='3a'>text1a</a>
    <a class='side-sub-1 blue' href='something3/something3B' data-id='3b'>text1b</a>
  </div>
</nav>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const result = await page.$$eval('[class^="menu-"] > *', els =>
    els.reduce((a, e, i) => {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        a.push([
          e.getAttribute("data-id"),
          e.textContent.trim(),
          e.getAttribute("href"),
          e.getAttribute("id"),
        ]);
      }
      else {
        a.at(-1).push(
          [...e.querySelectorAll('[class^="side-sub')].map(e => [
            e.getAttribute("data-id"),
            e.textContent.trim(),
            e.getAttribute("href"),
          ])
        );
      }
      return a;
    }, [])
  );
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Here, the assumption is that the `<a>` and `<div>` elements alternate as immediate children of the menu element. If we're at an even element, it's an `<a>`, so we should create a new node. Otherwise, we're at a `<div>`; append the child data to the last `<a>` node.

Other approaches are possible, such as selecting the `<a>` elements, then traversing to the next sibling to dive into the `<div>`s.

---

As a side nitpick mentioned in the comments, I think you're setting yourself up for future trouble using mixed-type arrays. I'd use objects for anything mixed-type. Arrays are usually iterated with loops while objects are accessed by individual properties to extract distinct characteristics. An array of `People` objects would make much more sense like:

```js
const people = [
  {name: "jack", age: 34, gender: "male"},
  {name: "jill", age: 27, gender: "female"},
];

for (const person of people) {
  console.log(person.name, person.age, person.gender);
}
```

than:

```js
const people = [
  ["jack", 34, "male"],
  ["jill", 27, "female"],
];

for (const person of people) {
  console.log(person[0], person[1], person[2]);
}
```

In the second example, a `Person` being an array makes no apparent sense. There's no concept of the "order" of a person's characteristics (by what metric would "age" be *second* and "gender" be *third*?), and there's no relationship between a *1* and an *age*.

A single person isn't an ordered series of homogeneous items, it's an unordered collection of heterogeneous properties. On the other hand, `people` *is* an ordered series of homogeneous items (each item in the array is the same type as every other).

Typing mixed-type arrays is extremely awkward to accomplish in typed languages and for good reason--it shouldn't be done. To use mixed-type arrays involves constant typechecking and casting; basically a lot of banging square screw into round pegholes.

Dynamically typed languages make it easier, but still relatively awkward and no less of an antipattern.

In rare cases when you need to iterate an object's properties, there's `Object.entries/keys/values`. In the opposite direction, if you find you're frequently using `Object.entries/keys/values`, you probably want to switch to an array.

I'd only suggest the array-based structure if an API requires it or you're dumping to CSV (but any decent CSV writer would have a way to write an array of objects, treating each key as a column label).

Comment: I use ` for (let [i,] of categories.entries()) {
        categories[i].push([]); 
        for (let [j,] of subcategories.entries()) {
            if (subcategories[j][2].includes(categories[i][2])) {
                categories[i][4].push(subcategories[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    let result = categories; ` your 'zip' will return incorrect results.

Comment: Sorry, what's the point of that code? That code looks pretty difficult to work with. If you just want the key, you can use `for (const key of categories.keys()) {}` instead of doing `entries()` and tossing out the value with destructuring. As mentioned in my post, you probably want to avoid `Object.entries/keys/values()`. Try using arrays if you're iterating objects this aggressively. The `[2]` and `[4]` should probably be named object properties. "2" and "4" have no obvious semantic value.

Comment: How does my zip return incorrect results? I have a complete, runnable example in the answer that uses your exact HTML structure that provides your exact output. Did you try running it and looking at the output? If it doesn't match the results when applied to the actual site, then please share that site or provide more accurate HTML so the problem can be reproduced. Thanks.

Comment: Back to the code you wrote, you don't have to iterate an object to check whether a key exists, just look it up with `obj[key]`. There's no need to "zip" objects per se. That's an array operation. At any rate, `categories.entries()` isn't likely valid JS. It'd have to be `Object.entries(categories)` if you're using the builtin approach.

Comment: added my full code to the question, you can run it to see the output.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I see how my solution isn't what you want yet. Looking closer, your HTML looks wrong. Are those `<div>` elements supposed to be closed? As I  mentioned in my first comment, I'm pretty sure something has been lost in translation. Please see my updated answer.